# How can I refresh an Entity Framework connection without disposing of the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After a few years of using Entity Framework in our applications without issue, our company has starting deploying laptops to our users. The laptops are being used on-site, with a direct, wired connection to our network.

Since then, we have seen a huge increase of crashes within our programs, with the exception logs showing

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. 
(provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
```

My theory is that the issue stems from the fact that the laptops, unlike the PCs, go to sleep. I think that the network adapter is being disabled when the laptop goes to sleep, and re-enabled when it wakes back up. I think our programs are still trying to communicate with the server using a connection that is no longer there.

So, my idea was to respond to:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged
```

I can detect when it wakes up and refresh the connection. The trouble is that the only way that I can seem to do this is to dispose of the current DbContext and instantiate a new one.

The problem with this is that any uncommitted changes are then lost. If the user has been working all day on updating a record, they would lose their work. Not only that, but we would have to go through all of our applications, and all of our viewmodels and incorporate some sort of kick out of edit mode with notifications to the user. Not pretty at all.

A second idea I've had was to create a method to clone a DbContext . When the computer wakes up, I could create a new DbContext and copy the state from the old one before disposing of it... but some of our data models are massive, and creating a deep clone method for each would be quite the undertaking.

It occurs to me that this might still be the way we have to go... but I'd be stupid not to check if anyone knows of a way to refresh the connection of an Entity Framework DbContext without losing it's current state.

I would appreciate any advice that anyone might have.

Comment: not sure what kind of design you have but keeping a large unsaved info in memory is not a good idea. You should somehow periodically auto-save the info. At least with that the loss info if any will be minimized as much as possible. Many applications (including web apps) use this strategy.

Comment: That's a fair point. The reason why we don't auto-save is because we allow users to decided whether to save changes or cancel. To do so, there are two strategies: 1) create a copy of the original data in memory when an edit starts, maintain live updates to the database as data is changed, on cancel update the data with the old copy. 2) Keep a working copy in memory, and only persist to the database when the user chooses to save their changes. From an implementation perspective, the second option is simpler, and is the method we use. That said, it does lead to issues like the one seen above.

Comment: Isn't there an event available which occurs before the laptop goes to sleep? You could save beforehand, close the connection and when it wakes up just open it again.

Comment: @Matt Yes, I can use the same event handler I mentioned to detect when the the system is about to sleep, but whether I detect the change before or after sleep, I'm facing the same issues. I can't just save, as the user might have been messing with the data, expecting to be able to cancel. And closing and opening the Entity Framework Connection doesn't actually refresh it. It would still try to open using the expired adapter. The only way I've seen to get a new connection is to dispose of the whole DbContext. The DbContext.Database.Connection property is readonly, so I can't just replace it.

Comment: In that case the only way I could think of is to serialize it before and deserialize it after wakeup, eg if you create a FIFO queue (which could be just a file) to ensure doing the updates in the right order.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, whether it will help in your specific case, but you can check the status of the connection used by your `DbConetxt` class and eventually reopen it.

```
if(context.Database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
    context.Database.Connection.Open();
}
```

it it also possible to pass a connection to the `DbContext` in it's constructor and manage this connection manually.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("{connectionString}"));
var context =  new DbContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false);

...

if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
    conn.Open(); 
}
context.SaveChanges(); 

...

context.Dispose();
conn.Dispose();
```

There are some limitations, if you want to use this code in the EF 5 or earlier versios. See [official documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456849.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to comment but I don't have enough reputation points to do that, so anyway I was wondering if it is not possible to work in a disconnected state with Entity Framework? Maybe the article in the link below can help:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the issue of Entity Framework trying to communicate using a dead connection. That said, it is a clear article on how to attach entities to a context, which could be very helpful should I have to create a clone method... rather than creating new entries, I could attach the existing entries that are marked added or modified from my old context. That would take a little experimenting, but it is still a very good resource. Thank you.